# What is the difference between ipython TerminalInteractiveShell and InteractiveShell?

Tags: python, configuration, ipython

The ipython [documentation](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/options/terminal.html) has a long list of configurable options. Some are for the `TerminalInteractiveShell`, some are for the `InteractiveShell`. Some options appear in one in the documentation and in the other when I generate a `ipython_config.py` from the command line. Is there any rhyme or reason to this? What is the reason for having both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking through the [list of modules](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/index.html) in the docs, we have

> `IPython.core.application`: An application for IPython.
>
> `IPython.core.interactiveshell`: Main IPython class.
>
> `IPython.terminal.ipapp`: The Application object for the command line
> `ipython` program.
>
> `IPython.terminal.interactiveshell`: IPython terminal interface using
> prompt_toolkit

[`InteractiveShell`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.interactiveshell.html#IPython.core.interactiveshell.InteractiveShell) is the base iPython shell class, which can be subclassed for different purposes. [`TerminalInteractiveShell`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.terminal.interactiveshell.html#IPython.terminal.interactiveshell.TerminalInteractiveShell) is one such specific subclass. It inherits from `InteractiveShell`, and is the specific shell that runs when we type "ipython" into the command line.

One example of a config option that's available for `TerminalInteractiveShell` but *not* the base `InteractiveShell` is [`confirm_exit`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/options/terminal.html#configtrait-TerminalInteractiveShell.confirm_exit). This seems reasonable, since the "Do you really want to exit" question is only really relevant when there's a human pressing Control-D inside the shell.

Practically, if you're just trying to configure your command line ipython shell, changing either the `InteractiveShell` or `TerminalInteractiveShell` version of an option would work because `TerminalInteractiveShell` inherits the base class's options. However, it's safer to only edit the more specific `TerminalInteractiveShell` ones, since the base class is still used in non-terminal situations, and changing its settings could lead to unexpected behavior there. For example:

- [This Jupyter Notebook tutorial](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/blob/6.2.0/docs/source/examples/Notebook/Importing%20Notebooks.ipynb) uses `InteractiveShell` to transform a notebook code cell into executable Python
- [This test class](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/rel-4.1.2/IPython/core/tests/test_pylabtools.py#L150) in the ipython source code creates a shell (inheriting from plain `InteractiveShell`) for each test.

Hope this was helpful!